# Apt-get on a ipv6-only Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, apt, ipv6

I have a hosted Ubuntu virtual server that only has an ipv6 address. I can ping6 it, and `ssh -6` to it without any problems but any time I try to use `apt-get update`, the entire process times out.

I've tried putting a `99force-ipv6` file containing `Acquire::ForceIPv6 "true";` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`, which doesn't change anything.

Completely out of ideas..

Comment: Which mirror are you using? It probably does not have IPV6.

Comment: What's the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`? Launchpad PPAs don't work without IPv4 (yet – there's a years-old open bug for that somewhere).

Comment: Not using any PPA's at all on this system and the /etc/apt/sources.list uses http://archive.ubuntu.com, so I'd *think* it would support ipv6..

Comment: Maybe use `netselect` to select the fastest (working) server? see https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-select-the-fastest-apt-mirror-on-ubuntu-linux

Answer (score 0):

If you don't own a NAT64-gateway, try to use one of the public gateways:

A list is here:

[some public DNS64/NAT64 gateways](https://go6lab.si/current-ipv6-tests/nat64dns64-public-test/)

The use is quite simple: 
set your DNS-resolver to one of the entries of list, for example `2001:67c:27e4:15::6411`.

The classic way would be to edit the `/etc/resolv.conf`

If you are using some DNS-helpers, you may adjust the value at a different place.

Comment: I *had* been using the Google ipv6 DNS (2001:4860:4860::8888/2001:4860:4860::8844) but adding your suggested 2001:67c:27e4:15:6411 before the Google addresses fixed the problem.. Not sure why, or just what a "DNS64/NAT64 gateway *is*) but I'm able to update the system  Thanks!!!

Comment: DNS64 adds AAAA-Records to hosts, which have originally no AAAA-Record. Of course they still don't have an IPv6-address, so a IPv6-address is taken from a NAT64-gateway. Ideally a IPv6-only-host-user should know about this technique.